# How to retrieve or remove bios password for compaq 620 laptop?

Tags: laptop, bios

I want to run Android Simulator on my pc which requires virtualization enabled from bios.I am not able to goto bios because bios is locked with password.Please tell me how can i unlock bios so that i can change the vitualization setting?

I have searched on google but not getting correct solution.

**EDIT:**

i tried

1. Remvoing the bios cell,hard drive,battery for 10 minutes.
2. [How to enable virtualization without using bios?](https://superuser.com/questions/1001877/how-to-enable-virtualization-without-using-bios/1001888#1001888)

**On removing bios cell clock is wiped out but bios password is not reset**

Comment: Would you mind using a search engine for such a baisc question which hundreds of people have asked before. Actually, your laptop's user manual should be able to tell you how to do it.

Comment: Thanks for telling me that a simple google search get the solution.I have already google it but none of option work for my machine.That i why i left with option to post here

Comment: "I have already google it but none of option work for my machine."  Unfortunately, we're not mind readers. :)  So please include what you've tried already (specifically), and what the results were.

Comment: The solution you posted i tried it.They i have given a number of password & try them that does not work.Even the person who posted that question didn't found solution for that also.If answer is accepted only then post a solution.@techie007